# Flex layout strange behavior when set the height in one of the elements

Tags: css, flexbox, angular-material2

In the following GIF, is possible to see that when I set a `height` to the footer element, the layout adds an space between the sidenav and the footer.

[image]

What´s the problem here? How can I change the height of the footer element without this behavior? My css is:

```
.flex-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}


.flex-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    justify-content: center; /* center items vertically, in this case */
    align-items: center;     /* center items horizontally, in this case */
}

.flex-sidenav {    
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 200px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);    
}

.flex-footer {    
    max-height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    flex-direction: column;  /* make main axis vertical */
    justify-content: center; /* center items vertically, in this case */
    align-items: center;     /* center items horizontally, in this case */
}
```

Comment: what about the HTML code ?

Comment: Why max-height? Just use height. Also it is probably the position fixed, you can create a sticky footer layout easier using flexbox

Comment: Why -1? The question is very clear and well formulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container is set to be positioned 60px from the bottom of the document, however the footer is only 50px in height, leaving a 10px gap.

I would recommend reading [this guide on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), as it include an example at the bottom similar to what you are trying to achieve without the unnecessary use of positioning.

Comment: That´s correct, was just a lack of attention. Thank´s for the answer! The link mentioned, is very good, I already knew it.